# Why does my project need cordova prepare command to be run twice?

Tags: android, cordova, prepared-statement

In my cordova project I for some reason have to run `cordova prepare android` twice before all the plugins are added. There are no errors the first time around.

I'm using `cordova-android@^8.1.0`. And

These are the configuration files that are used. There are some additional files, but they aren't relevant to the issue.
I've tried to use `cordova build android`, which results in the same issue.

config.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="dualinventive.mtinfo3000" ios-CFBundleIdentifier="com.dualinventive.mtinfo3000" version="1.4.5" windows-packageVersion="1.4.4.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
    <name>MTinfo 3000</name>
    <description>MTinfo 3000</description>
    <author email="maarten.manders@dualinventive.com" href="http://dualinventive.com">Dual Inventive</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="http://*.mtinfo3000.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="https://*.mtinfo3000.com" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="https://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="https://sentry.io" />
    <vs:features />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*.mtinfo3000.com" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />
        <hook src="scripts/android/010_copy_build_extras.js" type="after_platform_add" />
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
            <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-navigation href="*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="1024" src="res/icons/ios/icon-1024.jpg" width="1024" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-83.5-2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="167" src="res/icons/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" />
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" />
        <icon height="30" src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" />
        <icon height="310" src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="44" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" width="44" />
        <icon height="106" src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" />
        <icon height="70" src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" />
        <icon height="71" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" width="71" />
        <icon height="170" src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" />
        <icon height="50" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="120" src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="150" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" />
        <icon height="360" src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <icon height="62" src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" />
        <icon height="173" src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="android">
        <splash density="hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <splash src="res/screens/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="windows">
        <splash height="300" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" />
        <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
        <splash height="1920" src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="wp8">
        <splash height="800" src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True" />
    <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
    <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#009EE0" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
    <preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="interceptbackbutton" value="false" />
    <preference name="WindowsStoreDisplayName" value="MTinfo 3000" />
    <preference name="WindowsStoreIdentityName" value="DualInventive.MTinfo3000" />
    <preference name="WindowsStorePublisherName" value="Dual Inventive" />
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="9.0" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-compat" spec="^1.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="git+https://github.com/dualinventive/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="^2.4.3">
        <variable name="GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="To share with other MTinfo users" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" spec="^1.0.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.5.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker" spec="~5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-nativestorage" spec="2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-cookie-manager" spec="https://github.com/teunsteenbekkers/cordova-plugin-cookie-manager.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" spec="^1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-localization-strings" spec="git+https://github.com/cozy/cordova-plugin-localization-strings.git" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-download" spec="git+https://github.com/dualinventive/cordova-plugin-background-download.git#0.3.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.2.3">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION" value="27.+" />
        <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="11.6.2" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-windows-webview" spec="^0.5.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="^5.0.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" spec="git+https://github.com/dualinventive/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="sentry-cordova" spec="^0.16.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-open-native-settings" spec="git+https://github.com/dualinventive/Cordova-open-native-settings.git#v1.5.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-support-google-services" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-multidex" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^4.1.0">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
        <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION " value="To take pictures of equipment and upload them to MTinfo" />
        <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION " value="To select pictures from your library and upload them to MTinfo" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-open-native-settings" spec="git+https://github.com/dualinventive/Cordova-open-native-settings.git#v1.5.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.1.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-support-google-services" spec="~1.1.0" />
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-multidex" spec="~1.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-opener2" spec="^2.2.1">
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="windows" spec="^6.0.1" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^8.1.0" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="^4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mti",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0",
    "cordova-ios": "^4.5.5",
    "cordova-open-native-settings": "git+https://github.com/dualinventive/Cordova-open-native-settings.git#v1.5.2",
    "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": "^1.7.2",
    "cordova-plugin-background-download": "git+https://github.com/dualinventive/cordova-plugin-background-download.git#0.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-cookie-manager": "https://github.com/teunsteenbekkers/cordova-plugin-cookie-manager.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "^2.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "git+https://github.com/dualinventive/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-globalization": "^1.0.7",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "~1.5.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.1.2",
    "cordova-plugin-localization-strings": "git+https://github.com/cozy/cordova-plugin-localization-strings.git",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": "2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": "~5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "~2.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.2",
    "cordova-plugin-windows-webview": "^0.5.4",
    "cordova-support-google-services": "~1.1.0",
    "cordova-windows": "^6.0.1",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "git+https://github.com/dualinventive/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git",
    "phonegap-plugin-multidex": "~1.0.0",
    "phonegap-plugin-push": "2.2.3",
    "sentry-cordova": "^0.16.2"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "platforms": [
      "windows",
      "android",
      "ios"
    ],
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-open-native-settings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-compat": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-dialogs": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To share with other MTinfo users"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-globalization": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-nativestorage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-cookie-manager": {},
      "cordova-plugin-add-swift-support": {},
      "cordova-plugin-localization-strings": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-download": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-push": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V13_VERSION": "27.+",
        "FCM_VERSION": "11.6.2"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-windows-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "sentry-cordova": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION ": "To take pictures of equipment and upload them to MTinfo",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION ": "To select pictures from your library and upload them to MTinfo"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-opener2": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-support-google-services": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-multidex": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I expect the following to be present:

- android.json
- cordova-open-native-settings/
- cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/
- cordova-plugin-background-download/
- cordova-plugin-camera/
- cordova-plugin-compat/
- cordova-plugin-cookie-manager/
- cordova-plugin-device/
- cordova-plugin-dialogs/
- cordova-plugin-file/
- cordova-plugin-file-opener2/
- cordova-plugin-file-transfer/
- cordova-plugin-geolocation/
- cordova-plugin-globalization/
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
- cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/
- cordova-plugin-localization-strings/
- cordova-plugin-nativestorage/
- cordova-plugin-network-information/
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen/
- cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker/
- cordova-plugin-statusbar/
- cordova-plugin-whitelist/
- cordova-plugin-windows-webview/
- cordova-support-google-services/
- fetch.json
- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/
- phonegap-plugin-multidex/
- phonegap-plugin-push/
- sentry-cordova/

However only the following is:

- android.json
- cordova-open-native-settings/
- cordova-plugin-add-swift-support/
- cordova-plugin-camera/
- cordova-plugin-compat/
- cordova-plugin-cookie-manager/
- cordova-plugin-device/
- cordova-plugin-dialogs/
- cordova-plugin-file/
- cordova-plugin-geolocation/
- cordova-plugin-globalization/
- cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/
- cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard/
- cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/
- cordova-plugin-localization-strings/
- cordova-plugin-nativestorage/
- cordova-plugin-network-information/
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen/
- cordova-plugin-sslcertificatechecker/
- cordova-plugin-statusbar/
- cordova-plugin-whitelist/
- cordova-plugin-windows-webview/
- cordova-support-google-services/
- fetch.json
- phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/
- phonegap-plugin-multidex/
- phonegap-plugin-push/
- sentry-cordova/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the reason why this is an issue if your code actually runs as expected. 
Anyways, try cordova build android to see if any error occurs and/or try using --verbose to run the command.

Comment: I tried using verbose, no errors at all. I'm using the workaround of running it twice for now but it's hardly satisfactory.